# Should files with the "hdr" file extension end with newline characters?

Tags: file-format, hdr

I'm writing a script that enforces file formatting. One of the things it does is ensures that all text files end with newline characters.

One area which I'm unsure of is with `.hdr` files. These are images, the Linux `file` command says they are `Radiance HDR image data`, but they can be opened with a text editor, and the script interprets them as text files. As such, the script automatically appends newlines to these files.

Is this a good thing? How is this file type used? Is there any use case for these image files to be read as text? Is there any downside to making these files end with newline characters? Should I add an exception to my script to exclude `hdr` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the script automatically appends newlines to these [`.hdr`] files. Is this a good thing?

No. But it's probably not bad either. About the format [emphasis mine]:

> The file starts with the signature `#?RADIANCE` and then several lines listing the commands used to generate the image. […] There are also `key=value` declarations, including the line `FORMAT=32-bit_rle_rgbe`.
>
> After this is a blank line signifying the end of the header. A single line describes the resolution and pixel order. As produced by the Radiance tools this always takes the form of `-Y height +X width`. After this line follows the **binary pixel data**.

<sup>([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance_(software)#HDR_image_format))</sup>

I downloaded a `.hdr` file (`nancy_church_1.hdr`) from [this site](http://pfstools.sourceforge.net/hdr_gallery.html). I added a newline to a copy and even appended another file. I tested with `luminance-hdr`, the tool didn't complain.

I'm not surprised. The resolution is known; according to [this description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBE_image_format) there are four bytes per pixel and even if there's run-length encoding (rle) involved, it's still easy to know when to stop interpreting the binary pixel data. And there is no footer we could break.

Still other tools may or may not complain.

Even if it's harmless, adding a newline character to a `.hdr` file serves no purpose. One may want to add missing newlines in order to satisfy one of the [POSIX requirements regarding text files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25322168/10765659), but `.hdr` files are by design not text files in the first place. There's nothing to fix.

---

Answers to the explicit questions:

> Should files with the `hdr` file extension end with newline characters?

Somewhat tricky question because of semantics. No, they should not end with characters interpreted as newlines. They may end with `0x0a` bytes though. As a part of binary pixel data `0x0a` should not be interpreted as newline.

> How is this file type used?

As graphics.

> Is there any use case for these image files to be read as text?

You can read the header and the line describing the resolution and pixel order. You shouldn't try to read the *whole* file as text.

> Is there any downside to making these files end with newline characters?

There's a chance the files will take more blocks in the filesystem. Aside from this it's hard to say, some tools may complain. There are no benefits, so you can only make things worse or equal.

> Should I add an exception to my script to exclude `.hdr` files?

I think you should. I would. And I would rather rely on the `file` command, not on extension.